# duplicate a file multiple times and add write different lines in each file

Tags: text-processing, files

I know how to duplicate a file multiple times using `bash` commands, but now I want to know how to write in each of these duplicated files a different output. So for example:

I have 1 file with 5 lines and each line contains different annotations like:

```
1    16451824   16451824
2    17322876   17322876
3    17354363   17354363
4    17355234   17355234
5    17371253   17371253
```

And I have another file which I have duplicated 5 times.

Now I want to write in each of these files 1 line from my first file, so they all have a unique annotation.

What is the easiest way to do this using `bash`?

**Edit**

So my "Another file" which is duplicated 5 times looks like this:

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
```

And I would want a output like:

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
1 16451824  16451824  <-- first line from first file
```

Next file...

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
2 17322876  17322876 <-- second line from my first file
```

etc..

I hope that this is a bit more clearer

Comment: post the content of your "another file" and the final expected output

Comment: "Another file" which is duplicated 5 times :                                       
                            
1   22178279   22178279
2   22188618   22188618
3   22211006   22211006
4   22215993   22215993
5   25718484   25718484

Comment: sorry having some problems with pasting my content

Comment: Are the file names sequential like `f1.txt f2.txt f3...`?

Comment: yes they are sequential like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `coreutils`:

```
split -l1 file --filter='cat another - > "$FILE"'
```

The output files are named `xaa`, `xab` etc. by default:

```
$ head xa?
==> xaa <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
1    16451824   16451824

==> xab <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
2    17322876   17322876

==> xac <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
3    17354363   17354363

==> xad <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
4    17355234   17355234

==> xae <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
5    17371253   17371253
```

Comment: Thank you it work as i wanted it to be, it was very useful!

Comment: With any `split`: `{cat another; sed '$!r another' file; } | split -l6` or, if you don't know the no. of lines in `another` beforehand `n=$(wc -l <another); { cat another; sed '$!r another' file; } | split -l$((n+1))`

Comment: How would i do this if i want to skip the header and give names to the files with each one another number, like  file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc...

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v f2="$(cat file2)" '{ print f2 ORS $0 > "file"++c".txt" }' file1
```

- `file1` and `file2` - are your "first" and "another" files respectively
- `f2` - variable containing the contents of the `file2`

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head file[0-9]*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
1 16451824  16451824

==> file2.txt <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
2 17322876  17322876

==> file3.txt <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
3 17354363  17354363

==> file4.txt <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
4 17355234  17355234

==> file5.txt <==
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
5 17371253  17371253
```

Answer (score 2):

I mushed up this script, not the most optimum but works:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create an array of the lines in file f1
# create a counter
count=0
#declare an array
declare -a m

while IFS=$'\n' read -r data
do
    # Add each line to the m array
    m["$count"]="$data"
    # increase the count
    count=$((count+1))

done < "$1"    

# Declare another array to hold the duplicate files
# locations
declare -a c
c=(/path/to/duplicate/files/folder/*)
# Create another counter
f=0

for ((i=0; i<"${#c[@]}"; i++))
do
        # inject lines into the duplicate files
        echo "${m[$f]}" >> "${c[$i]}"
        f=$((f+1))
done
```

f1:

```
1    16451824   16451824
2    17322876   17322876
3    17354363   17354363
4    17355234   17355234
5    17371253   17371253
```

Results:

f2

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
1    16451824   16451824
```

f3

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
2    17322876   17322876
```

f4

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
3    17354363   17354363
```

f5

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
4    17355234   17355234
```

f6

```
1 40780020  40780020
2 41223003  41223003
3 43218205  43218205
4 43395462  43395462
5 43803907  43803907
5    17371253   17371253
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure someone will come up with a single line that can do this, but here is a simple sh script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script assumes the files that will have the line
# added are named f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt f4.txt f5.txt
#
# The data file contains the 5 lines that will be 
# copied to the 5 files.

# The "per line" data file
DATA=`cat f0.txt`

# The number of files that need to have a line added
F_LIST="1 2 3 4 5"

# NOTE: No error checking!!!
IFS="
"
for l in $DATA
do
    f=${F_LIST%% *}
    echo "$l" >> "f${f}.txt"
    F_LIST=${F_LIST#* }
done
exit
```