# Duplicate a file multiple times, write to duplicated files, sort the files, count position of specific lines after sorting

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, grep, terminal

Before I go to more in details, I want to point out that I already asked a certain part of this question -> [You can find it here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412201/duplicate-a-file-multiple-times-and-add-write-different-lines-in-each-file/412254#412254). I received some nice answers, but I need to do more so I'll repeat my question and add more details this time:

So I have a file with unique content that looks like this(lets call this `myUniqueFile`):

```
chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
chr1    28745756    28745756    7.905   5   
chr1    31227215    31227215    10.263  5
chr1    47562402    47562402    2.322   4
chr1    64859630    64859630    1.714   3
chr1    70805699    70805699    1.913   2
chr1    89760653    89760653    -0.1    0
chr1    95630169    95630169    -1.651  -1
```

These are all different locations with different scores as you can see.

And I have another file that looks like this(lets call this one `myDuplicationFile`:

```
chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
chr3    15540407    15540407    -1.391  -1
chr3    30648039    30648039    2.214   3
chr3    31663820    31663820    0.713   3
chr3    33093371    33093371    3.753   4
chr3    37050398    37050398    1.650   2
chr3    38053456    38053456    1.1     1
chr3    39597927    39597927    8.721   5
```

So to start with I would like to add lines(except the header) from  `myUniqueFile` to  `myDuplicationFile`, but I want them to be added in way that  `myDublicationFile` is duplicated for each new line that is added from `myUniqueFile`. So `myDublicationFile` keeps his standard content + 1 new line added from `myUniqueFile`. it should look something like this:

```
myDublicatedFile1.txt:

chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
chr3    15540407    15540407    -1.391  -1
chr3    30648039    30648039    2.214   3
chr3    31663820    31663820    0.713   3
chr3    33093371    33093371    3.753   4
chr3    37050398    37050398    1.650   2
chr3    38053456    38053456    1.1     1
chr3    39597927    39597927    8.721   5
chr1    28745756    28745756    0.905   1    <- first line from `myUniquefile`


myDublicatedFile2.txt:

chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
chr3    15540407    15540407    -1.391  -1
chr3    30648039    30648039    2.214   3
chr3    31663820    31663820    0.713   3
chr3    33093371    33093371    3.753   4
chr3    37050398    37050398    1.650   2
chr3    38053456    38053456    1.1     1
chr3    39597927    39597927    8.721   5
chr1    31227215    31227215    10.263  5    <- second line from `myUniquefile`
```

so for each new line added a new file is created like `myDublicatedFile3,4,5` etc..

After I have these `myDublicatedFiles` with the new added content, I would like to sort these files for a specific columns from high to low , (for the **phylop** column) I do this with  `for f in myDublicatedFile* ; do sort -g -r -k 3 $f >> $f.method1.txt` so this looks something like this:

myDublicatedFile1.method1.txt:

```
chr3    39597927    39597927    8.721   5
chr1    28745756    28745756    7.905   5 <- count 2
chr3    33093371    33093371    3.753   4
chr3    30648039    30648039    2.214   3
chr3    37050398    37050398    1.650   2
chr3    38053456    38053456    1.1     1
chr3    31663820    31663820    0.713   3
chr3    15540407    15540407    -1.391  -1
chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
```

So after I sort these files, I would like to know the position of the lines I added after the sorting. It seems logical to me to do something with "grep" and use a "count".

So for `myDublicatedFile1.method1.txt` is this count/rank 2 since the added line from `myUniquefile` ended up in the second place in the file.

After calculating the count/rank for the `phlop`**(method1)** column i would like to do a sort for the `GPS`**(method2)** column and than calculate the ranks of the added lines again. myDublicatedFile1.method1.method2.txt should look something like this:

```
chr3    39597927    39597927    8.721   5
chr1    28745756    28745756    7.905   5 
chr3    33093371    33093371    3.753   4
chr3    30648039    30648039    2.214   3
chr3    31663820    31663820    0.713   3
chr3    37050398    37050398    1.650   2
chr3    38053456    38053456    1.1     1
chr3    15540407    15540407    -1.391  -1
chromosoom  start    end       phylop   GPS
```

Its easy if the counts/rankings are written in different file so I can use these later for statistics. So the most important files are these count since I will end up use these :)

Something like:

countsForMethod1.txt:

```
29
3
5
6
50
etc.
```

countsForMethod2.txt:

```
7
3
21
45
etc..
```

Comment: It looks like that you don't need to form those `myDuplicatedFiles*` files explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by that? @WeijunZhou

Comment: I mean that if the ranking is what you really need, you don't need intermediate files. By the way, AFAIK there is not a good way to typeset multiline contents in comment, let alone codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the version of `split` from GNU `coreutils`, and a shell like `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` is available (for the process substitution feature being used here), you could modify the previous accepted answer to handle the header lines and sorting e.g.

```
tail -n +2 myUniqueFile | SHELL=$(command -v bash) split -l1 --filter='{ 
  head -n 1 myDuplicationFile &&
    sort -g -r -k4,4 <(tail -n +2 myDuplicationFile) -
  } > "$FILE"'
```

You could then use a simple `awk` one-liner to find the positions of the `myUniqueFile` entries in the output files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && NR>1 {a[$0]++; next} ($0 in a) {print FILENAME, FNR}' myUniqueFile xa?
xaa 3
xab 2
xac 4
xad 5
xae 5
xaf 8
xag 9
```

Rinse and repeat for the other methods / sort orders.

Comment: Thanks again @steeldriver for helping me out. it didn't quit work this time, I probably have a typo, so i used :   tail -n +2 sampleUnique.txt | split -l1 --filter='{ 
  head -n 1 standard.txt && cat <(tail -n +2 standard.txt) - | sort -g -r -k4,4 
  } > "$FILE" '           I received the flowing error ` bash: -c: line 1: sytax error: unexpected end of file split: with FILE=xaa, exit 1 from command: { head -n 1 standard.txt && cat <(tail -n +2 standard.txt) - sort -g -r -k4,4 } > "$FILE" `

Comment: i am not that good in formatting my comments yet sorry for that post, kinda new to stackexchange , basically it says i have a syntax error. the standard.txt file is myDuplicationFile and the sampleUnique.txt  is --> myUniqueFile. i hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: @OsmanAltun if you put the compound command on a single line, you will need to terminate it with a semicolon e.g. `'{ command1 && command2; } > "$FILE"'`

Comment: it works just the way i needed it, 1 small question: so after I sort them for method1. I want to sort the sorted(method1) files again. I used something like:  `for f in xa*.txt; do sort -g -r -k,k $f>> $f.method2.txt; done `    ,  but if i look at the out put i expect a different result. I sort first on the phylop colum and than the GPS column so the highest phylop score = 10.263 and the highest GPS =5 should be placed number one but they dont, do you know maybe why? Is it something i do wrong in the code or? Sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: it seems more to me like the sorting doesn't work good, instead of the code it self.. like if i sort on phylop it puts `2.213` above `2.322` which can't be good so the second sorting will automatically fail 2

Comment: I fixed the problem by using LC_ALL, it works now thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sorry that I have to ask it again but again I have problems with the sorting, it works on the the test files I use in this question, the real file is a bit bigger. Some days ago I fixed it with LC_ALL=C but it seems like that it worked only 1 time, now again it doesn't sort like it should.. Can you pls help me out 1 more time @steeldriver

Comment: I don't see the `--filter` option at all in the documentation for GNU coreutils `split` on RHEL 6.  Is it an extremely recent addition?

Comment: @Wildcard you can find it https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html  its there if you look good, but i don't think that my problem has something to do with that.

Comment: @OsmanAltun, yes, that's 8.29.  RHEL 6 has 8.4.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas the sorting still doesn't work as it should be unfortunately

Comment: @OsmanAltun can you provide a minimal example of a case that's not sorting in the desired way?

Comment: phyloP
-100
1.311
0.013
-0.608
-0.956
0.189
0.249
0.249
-0.859
0.249
-0.76
0.261

Comment: @steeldriver Its hard to show without showing the actual file, but as you can see above, it doesn't sort as it should have the exact code I use is : 'tail -n +2 myUniqueFile | split -l1 --filter='
{ head -n 1 myDuplicationFile.txt && cat <(tail -n +2 myDuplicationFile.txt) - | sort -n -r -43 ; } > "$FILE" ' `  like I said before it does work on the example file I used  here but it doesnt sort when I try it on the actual file which is a lot bigger.

Comment: after the files are produced , I can sort a file correct with `tail -n +2 xaa.txt| cut -f43| sort -n -r` , I assume that it can't sort properly when it has to work with lots of data at once

Comment: @steeldriver if you're okey with it I would like to send  you the real data files so you could see it your self, and maybe tell me what went wrong? if its not to much to ask.

Answer (score 3):

This script calculates ranks without creating temporary files (almost, one file will created - the `sorted_file`). Also, it sorts `myDuplicationFile` one time for the each method, then use it further.

```
#!/bin/bash

rank_determination() {
    # Sorts the "myDuplicationFile" one time
    # The "sorted_file" will be used further.
    ###
    tail -n +2 myDuplicationFile | sort -g -r -k "$1","$1" > sorted_file

    # gawk iterates through "myUniqueFile" line by line (except the first line).
    gawk -v field_number="$1" '
    NR != 1 {
        # Stores the needed value for the each line
        ###
        search_value=$field_number
        cnt=1

        # then, it checks the specified column in the "sorted_file"
        # line by line for the value, which is less than 
        # the "search_value" from the "myUniqueFile".
        ###
        while((getline < "sorted_file") > 0) {
            if($field_number < search_value)
                break
            cnt++
        }

        print cnt
        # closing is needed for reading the file from the beginning
        # each time. Else, "getline" will read line by line consistently.
        ###
        close("sorted_file")
    }' myUniqueFile
}

# I create a function, which takes
# the number argument, which means the column number:
# "4" for "phylop" column, "5" for the "GPS" column.
#
# The function creates output, which you can redirect
# to the needed file.
# Call this function multiple times with different arguments
# for the each needed column.
rank_determination 4 > method1.txt
rank_determination 5 > method2.txt
```

**Output**

```
tail -n +1 -- method*
==> method1.txt <==
2
1
3
4
4
7
8

==> method2.txt <==
2
2
3
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71278/discussion-on-answer-by-minimax-duplicate-a-file-multiple-times-write-to-duplic).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what @WeijunZhou said in his comment, you don't need to make all those temporary files to do this.

The following perl script will calculate the counts for your Method 1 (phylops) and Method 2 (GPS) sorting, in one pass through both files.

It works by keeping a sorted list (array) of the phylop and GPS values from the duplicate file, and then (for each line of the unique file) calculating where the phylop and GPS value would have sorted into their respective sorted arrays.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# get uniqfile and dupefile names from cmd line, with defaults
my $uniqfile = shift || 'myUniqueFile';
my $dupefile = shift || 'myDuplicationFile';

# Read in the dupefile and keep the phylops and GPS values.
# This could take a LOT of memory if dupefile is huge.
# Most modern systems should have no difficulty coping with even
# a multi-gigabyte dupefile.
my @phylop=();
my @GPS=();

open(DUPE,"<",$dupefile) || die "couldn't open '$dupefile': $!\n";
while(<DUPE>) {
  chomp;
  next if (m/^chromosoom/);

  my($chr,$start,$end,$phylop,$GPS) = split;
  push @phylop, $phylop + 0; # add 0 to make sure we only ever store a number
  push @GPS, $GPS + 0;
};
close(DUPE);

# Sort the @phylop and @GPS arrays, numerically descending
@phylop = sort {$a <=> $b} @phylop;
@GPS = sort {$a <=> $b} @GPS;

print "Method1\tMethod2\n";

# Now find out where the phylop and GPS value from each line of uniqfile
# would have ended up if we had sorted it into dupefile
open(UNIQ,"<",$uniqfile) || die "couldn't open '$uniqfile': $!\n";
while (<UNIQ>) {
  next if (m/^chromosoom/);
  chomp;

  my $phylop_sort_line=1;
  my $GPS_sort_line=1;

  my($chr,$start,$end,$phylop,$GPS) = split;

  for my $i (0..@phylop-1) {
    $phylop_sort_line++ if ($phylop < $phylop[$i]);
    $GPS_sort_line++ if ($GPS < $GPS[$i]);
  };

  #printf "%i\t%i\t#%s\n", $phylop_sort_line, $GPS_sort_line, $_;
  printf "%i\t%i\n", $phylop_sort_line, $GPS_sort_line;  
};
close(UNIQ);
```

when run against the sample data you provided above, the output is:

```
$ ./counts-for-methods.pl
Method1 Method2
2       1
1       1
3       2
4       3
4       5
7       7
8       7
```

The script completely ignores the header line in both files, so these line numbers may be off by one if your current algorithm counts them.

It also assumes that the values from the unique file will always sort immediately before an identical value in the duplicate file.  If this is not what you want, change the `<` comparisons in the `for my $i (0..@phylop)` loop to `<=`.

If you need the values for Method 1 and Method 2 separately, you can easily extract them with `awk`.  Or the `perl` script can easily be modified to open two output files, one for each method, and print the respective values to each file.

---

here's a version for dealing with 151 fields in the input lines.  I don't have such an input file, so I tested it with the '5 fields version' that has been commented out in the code.  The output was the same as the version above.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

# get uniqfile and dupefile names from cmd line, with defaults
my $uniqfile = shift || 'myUniqueFile';
my $dupefile = shift || 'myDuplicationFile';

my @phylop=();
my @GPS=();

# Read in the dupefile and keep the phylops and GPS values.
# This could take a LOT of memory if dupefile is huge.
# Most modern systems should have no difficulty coping with even
# a multi-gigabyte dupefile.
open(DUPE,"<",$dupefile) || die "couldn't open '$dupefile': $!\n";
while(<DUPE>) {
  chomp;
  next if (m/^chromosoom/);

  my @fields = split;

# 151 fields version:
  push @phylop, $fields[42]+0;
  push @GPS, $fields[150]+0;

# 5 fields version:
#  push @phylop, $fields[3]+0;
#  push @GPS, $fields[4]+0;

};
close(DUPE);

# Sort the @phylop and @GPS arrays, numerically descending
@phylop = sort {$b <=> $a} @phylop;
@GPS = sort {$b <=> $a} @GPS;

print "Method1\tMethod2\n";

# Now find out where the phylop and GPS from each line of uniqfile
# would have ended up if we had sorted it into the dupefile
open(UNIQ,"<",$uniqfile) || die "couldn't open '$uniqfile': $!\n";
while (<UNIQ>) {
  next if (m/^chromosoom/);
  chomp;

  my $phylop_sort_line=1;
  my $GPS_sort_line=1;

  my @fields = split;

  for my $i (0..@phylop-1) {

# 151 fields version:
    $phylop_sort_line++ if ($fields[42] < $phylop[$i]);
    $GPS_sort_line++ if ($fields[150] < $GPS[$i]);

# 5 fields version:
#    $phylop_sort_line++ if ($fields[3] < $phylop[$i]);
#    $GPS_sort_line++ if ($fields[4] < $GPS[$i]);
  };

  #printf "%i\t%i\t#%s\n", $phylop_sort_line, $GPS_sort_line, $_;
  printf "%i\t%i\n", $phylop_sort_line, $GPS_sort_line;

};
close(UNIQ);
```

Comment: Note: sorting the arrays in perl will also take a lot of memory.  If the dupefile is huge, you may want to pre-sort it into two different files, and read the `@phylop` and `@GPS` arrays from the two differently sorted files.

Comment: thank you for the comment, the reason I wanted to keep the files is to just look in them after wards so that the sorting went good and the rest of   the information can quite be important, in this example I only use 5 columns , normally the files consist of 151 columns. So I want test your perl code for my real files, do I have to put all the column names , I think that's not so efficient , you might help me out with that, I'm completely new to perl!

Comment: no, you don't need to list all the column names.  As long as you know what column number(s) you're interested in.  I only used named variables because there were only 5.   you can split into an array instead - e.g. `my @fields = split;`...then (remembering that perl arrays start from 0, not 1) `$fields[fieldnumber]` contains the value you want.  e.g. instead of `$phylop`, use `$fields[3]`

Comment: as for verifying the results, i tend to test code thoroughly against a small but representative sample until I'm certain that it's working perfectly.  for large files, visual inspection is going to introduce huge risk of human error, tired eyes, etc anyway.

Comment: I didn't get the syntax correct for `my @fields =split'   and 
 ` $fields[fieldnumber] ` ,  assume phylop is column 43 and GPS is 151 , can you maybe edit it in the code so I can see it. thank you very much!

Comment: ok, i added a version that shows how to do it.  if you have any more questions, leave a comment here and I'll see them sometime tomorrow (it's almost 1.30am here in australia, time to sleep)

Comment: no problem.  btw, given the kind of data you seem to be working with, you may want to take a look at http://bioperl.org/ - "*The Bioperl Project is an international association of users & developers of open source Perl tools for bioinformatics, genomics and life science*".  Note: much of the bioperl stuff is available pre-packaged for several distros including debian.

Comment: you can compare it with `Biopython` or `Biojava` I suppose, thanks again, I'll test the code

Answer (score 1):

Just to save some typing, I will call the `myUniqueFile` `sample` and `myDuplicationFile` `standard`.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

(
while read line; do
  echo $line|cat standard -|tail -n +2|sort -g -r -k 4|awk '/^chr1/{print FNR}' >> countsForMethod1.txt
  echo $line|cat standard -|tail -n +2|sort -g -r -k 5|awk '/^chr1/{print FNR}' >> countsForMethod2.txt
done
) <(tail -n +2 sample)
```

**Explanation**: The whole while loop is wrapped by a pair of parentheses to make `bash` treat it as a single command. This command takes the file `sample` as its input, with the header line stripped using the `tail` command. It is then consumed by the `read` command one line a time. That means inside the loop, `$line` is one line from the file `sample`. The variable is echoed and pipelined to `cat` to generate the `myDuplicated*` files, only that they are generated "on the fly" and never written to disk. The header lines are dropped by the `tail` before the files are sorted. `awk` is then used to find out which line the sample is on.

**Edit**:
I think the `split` has its advantages while this answer eliminates the need for intermediate files.

Comment: thank you for the explanation as well for the code, i did go for the split version in the end.